# User management in multi-saas with shared auth service

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, saas

I have a saas platform I'm building and I'm currently struggling with how to model my auth flow. The system is going to be multiple multi-tenant applications but I would like to unify user authorization & authentication. Basically, each US State will have its own web app/resource server/database and every county in that state will be a separate tenant. I cannot combine all states into one application, so that is not an option.

I would like to throw all users and their information/password into one database connected to my auth service. But each county (tenant) admin within each state (web app) needs to be able to add & manager their users and their roles. So the auth service needs to be aware of all the different tenants across each application. I also need to be able to link items created in each database to the user that created it. If I create object "X" and another user in my county views that item, they can see "Kovaci" created this.

I also do NOT want SSO between states but if possible I would like users to be a part of multiple tenants within one app (not a requirement though). Native iOS/Mobile apps are another client I need to support with this flow.

I used this bitoftech article to base off of: http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/comment-page-1/#comments

And here is my paint quick mockup: [multi saas design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s492i.png)

My question is just generally how do I design this auth part? Can I store all users in one auth db like my goal? If so, how do tenant admins manage them and how do I link tables in my separate app db's to the users' current info in the auth db?